# How to put variable from angular controller in confirm message in html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'd like to put angular variable in confirm message. After many tries, any solution doesn't work for me:

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Do you want to manage ' + {{item.name}} + ' with ...?')" 
   ng-href="/link={{item.ipAddress}}">{{item.name}}</a>
```

Can anybody help? (Works fine without {{item.name}} in confirm message)

Comment: Can you provide something more concrete to look, may a snippet demo over jsFiddle or codepen. That will be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't be helpful in this case. It's all about why {{}} doesn't work in this particular situation. I'm delivering html template and I'm forced to use js code in that way.

Comment: providing html template means the template expects some data object where it can find value of item and then name from that item object, See if this template has access to that item object.

Comment: yes, of course name under link looks as expected

Comment: there is only problem with access to item.name in confirm message

Comment: I dont know in chrome console i tried
`var item = {};
item.name = 'hello';
confirm(`Do you want to manage  ${item.name} with ...?`)`
And it worked, so if template has access to item object, it can display expected result.

Comment: For me also in chrome it shows 'Do you want to manage ${item.name} with ...?' in confirm dialog, under link I can see proper value

Comment: replace confirm ( '' ) with confirm(``) these are backticks which you can find in the top left part of keyboard under esc key.
See  :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: onclick="return confirm(`Do you want to manage ${item.name} with...?`)" I'm degustated, this doesn't show any confirm dialog...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Angular framework, I would suggest you to use `(click)` directive.

Then you can use a method defined in the controller linked to the template.

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vai2ct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**Component**

```
  confirm(item): void{
    confirm(`Do you want to manage ${item.name} with...?`);
  }
```

**Template**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="confirm(item)">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please note that template literals are used to make `${item.name}` valid inside string. Refer  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.
Yup, answer is correct, i was gonna post the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using external component. I have to put this action into html code.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar thanks for this doc :) I'm not sure to understand what does *external component* mean

Comment: ${item.name} doesn't work it shows "{item.name}" instead of value

Comment: Please can you provide an example on Stackblitz ?

Comment: External component means I can only provide custom html template for row of the list. After I'd like to have confirm message and then redirect.

Comment: Providing example in this case is useless unfortunately... It's all about why {{}} tag doesn't work correctly

Comment: Then show us more code, not the view only. And more, we don't know if you're talking about Angular or AngularJS.. Tags have been changed without knowing...

Answer (score 0):

You **can** access the scope without changing the controller code. You just need to add an `id` to your controller. Here is what it will look like:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = {
    "name": "NAME"
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl" id="ctrl1">

    <a onclick="confirm('Do you want to manage ' + angular.element(document.getElementById('ctrl1')).scope().item.name + ' with ...?')">
      {{item.name}}
    </a>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding of the question, I am writing the best solution as per me, which can help you resolve the issue.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.item = {
    "name": "Ronit Mukherjee",
    "ipAddress": "192.197.85.39"
  }

  $scope.myFunc = function(name, ipAddress) {
    if (confirm("Do you want to manage " + name + " with ...?")) {
      $window.location.href = "/link=" + ipAddress;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>AngularJS</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <a ng-click="myFunc(item.name,item.ipAddress)">{{item.name}}</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you still face any issue, then feel free to comment and clear the doubts.